# SetBitmapBits not setting Captured HBITMAP on Window

Tags: winapi, gdi, hbitmap

I want to get a 500x500 HBITMAP of my screen from 0x0 (top-left) and draw it on my window.
Here goes my code. `SaveBitmap()` Saves the HBITMAP and its working Fine.

```
int scrnw = 500;
int scrnh = 500;

HDC shdc=GetWindowDC(NULL);
HWND win=WindowFromDC(shdc);

HDC cdc=CreateCompatibleDC(shdc);
HBITMAP temp=CreateCompatibleBitmap(shdc,scrnw,scrnh);
PAINTSTRUCT ps;

shdc=BeginPaint(win,&ps);
HBITMAP oldb=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(cdc,temp);
BitBlt(cdc,0,0,scrnw,scrnh,shdc,0,0,SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(cdc,oldb);
EndPaint(win,&ps);
char * buffer;
buffer=new char[scrnw*scrnh*4];
GetBitmapBits(temp,scrnw*scrnh*4,buffer);

SaveBitmap("C:\\scan.bmp", temp);

HDC hdc=GetWindowDC(hwnd);
HBITMAP scrn = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,500,500);
SetBitmapBits(scrn,500*500*4,buffer);
```

The Problem is the Captured Image is not being drawn on the Window.Where am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

`shdc` is "forgetting" the screen when you perform `shdc=BeginPaint()`, so there's nowhere to get the image from.

Let it stay with `shdc=GetWindowDC(NULL)` and use another HDC for `hdcMyPaint=BeginPaint()`. After blitting to `cdc`, blit also to your `hdcMyPaint`. That should do it.